# Customizing the post to facebook in Sharekit2.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, sharekit

I have integrated the latest sharekit code into my project. I am able to click in, to go to the facebook and able to see the text I am going to post.

I would like to change two things.

Firstly, I am not able to see the cancel or post button because of my app picture at top. So I would like to set the view to be scrollable. How do I change that?

Secondly, I would like to remove the keyboard after I press return, or I want a way to remove the keyboard.

Thirdly, when i click the text edit, it gives me Error: HTTP status code: 404. How to solve this?

Need some help on this..Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

if you use following code it will dissmiss the keyboard.

```
[self.view Endediting:YES];
```

Comment: this is for the second one right. I have to add it together with SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem?

Comment: @laksh yes this is to only dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: i need your help slightly. for the first thing, how do u remove the banner instead of making it scrollable? any suggestion?

Comment: is the banner on navigation bar ?

Comment: if yes then Use  `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES ];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19917/discussion-between-laksh-and-siba-prasad-hota)

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourtextview resignFirstResponder];
```

this will remove the keyboard

Or as a general case, you can use this: `[self.view Endediting:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

ShareKit never seemed to be customizable. Personally, I had displeasure to integrate it into the project to post images to Flickr and Twitter, but nothing else. For what I see there now, ShareKit is still using old FacebookSDK (or at least it look so).
For better customization, I'd suggest to throw away Facebook from your ShareKit and just use new FacebookSDK.